# Does the number/expression above the sigma notation mean the last n-value, or the number of terms?

Tags: summation, notation, definition

The way I've understood it, is that the number or expression above the sigma function gives the number of terms. Here's an example:

$$\sum_{k=2}^4 k^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2$$

However, I have now seen another way of using the sigma function:

$$\sum_{k=2}^4 k^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2$$

The former example illustrates how I've learned to use it, the value above the sigma function denoting **the number of terms**. The latter example illustrates the other definition, where the value above denotes the last value. Which of these definitions are correct? And if both are correct, how does one tell the reader which one is being used?

Comment: It means the last $k$ value

Comment: @J.W.Tanner well is there a way of notating it so that it means the number of terms?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=a}^{a+b-1} f(k)\;$ has $b$ terms

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation

Comment: @J.W.Tanner does the above notation apply to ANY situation? Also, why is there a minus one there?

Comment: I’d recommend you read the Wikipedia link in the comment above.  $\{a,a+1,...,a+b-1\}$ has $b$ terms

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I will, but I just wonder, was the sigma function you commented with designed for this specific case, or is it a general rule that works in any situation?

Comment: I have NEVER seen the upper index on a sum meaning "the number of terms in the sum"- **except**, of course, where the lower index is 1.   I suspect the sum from 1 up is what you are used to seeing.   $\sum_{k=1}^3 k^2=1+ 4+ 9$ but $\sum_{k=2}^4 k^2=  4+ 9+ 16$  both have three terms even though the upper index in the second sum is 4.

Comment: @A.Kvåle:  I don’t understand your question in your last comment

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If "b" is any number/expression and "a" is any number, will a+b-1 yield the number of terms, always? It doesn't matter now though, I found a way to correct the math I did last time, so that the expression above the sigma function equals the last k-value, and not the number of terms.

Comment: As I said, if you want the number of terms to be $b$, sum from $k=a$ to $a+b-1$

Answer (score 1):

The number or expression on top of $\sum$ in a [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) indicates the highest value of the index.

For example, $\sum\limits_{k=2}^4 k^2=2^2+3^2+4^2$.

If you want the number of terms to be $b$, write $\sum\limits_{k=a}^{a+b-1}k^2.$

Note that, when $a=1$ (but not otherwise!), this is simply $\sum\limits_{k=1}^b k^2.$

Comment: But would this apply to any situation? For example, imagine a completely different sigma function: $$\sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1} k + 2 \times (k-3)$$ Or something completely different. Will "b" always amount to the number of terms?

Comment: Yes, there are $b$ numbers from $a$ to $a+b-1$ inclusive, no matter what the summand is

Comment: Ah, now I see. Sorry for my slow brain. Thanks! Would you like to check out my new question, where I'm asking for a verification of some solutions? I have high confidence in that they're correct, but I don't fully trust my precalc abilities and knowledge.